# What is the use of transform.Translate()?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

What is the difference between doing

```
transform.Translate(offset);
```

and

```
transform.position += offset;
```

Is there any smoothing or stuff in the background that the method is doing or is it just

```
public void Translate(Vector3 distance)
{
    this.position += distance;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`transform.Translate(offset)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html) moves by `offset` in local space. In other words, it takes the rotation of `transform` into account

`transform.postition += offset` moves by `offset` in world space. In other words, it does not take the rotation of `transform` into account.

Otherwise, they are the same. You can think of `transform.Translate` as:

```
public void Translate(Vector3 offset)
{
    this.position += this.TransformDirection(offset);
}
```

See [`transform.TransformDirection`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.TransformDirection.html) for more information.

`transform.Translate(offset, Space.World)` would be the same as `transform.position += offset`